# Insert or update PosgreSQL através do Python

Tags: sql, python, postgresql

Hoje estou utilizando o seguinte código para fazer uma chama via API e armazenar meus dados no banco de dados PostgreSQL:

```
  conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='DBNAME' user='USER' host='HOST' 
password='PASSWORD'")

insert = "INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5) 
VALUES"
```

....
Aqui tem uma lista onde extraio os dados em json e insiro no banco
.....

```
if len(gravar) >0 :
    cur = conn.cursor()
    y = b','.join(cur.mogrify(" 
(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in gravar)
    comando = insert + y.decode()
    try:
        cur.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE TABLE")
        cur.execute(comando)
        conn.commit()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)

cur.close()
print('Carga Completa')
else:
conn.close()
print('Nada a Inserir')
```

Para não sobrepor os dados estou fazendo um trucate antes de executar o insert.
Como eu poderia fazer um "insert or update" nesse comando, evitando assim ter que truncar a tabela?

Comment: Qual a versão do seu `PostgreSQL`?

Comment: Talvez a cláusual ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE possa ajuda-lo. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: Como mencionado você pode usar o `INSERT` com o `ON CONFLICT`. Tem algumas observações: o postgres precisa ser versão >=9.5; o `ON CONFLICT` valida a restrição correspondente a apenas um campo ou constraint.

Comment: @CamiloSantos Muito obrigado pela ajuda, coloquei o ON CONFLICT é funcionou normalmente!

Comment: Legal @Maursb!! Como sugestão, poste sua solução na resposta da pergunta. Dessa maneira se outra pessoa estiver com a mesma situação pode usar a sua solução.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei a cláusula ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ([link da documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html)) e retirei o truncate antes de inserir os dados.

Meu código ficou dessa forma:

```
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='DBNAME' user='USER' host='HOST' 
password='PASSWORD'")

insert = "INSERT INTO TABLE (COLUMN1,COLUMN2,COLUMN3,COLUMN4,COLUMN5) 
VALUES"
```

.... Aqui tem uma lista onde extraio os dados em json e insiro no banco .....

```
if len(gravar) >0 :
    cur = conn.cursor()
    y = b','.join(cur.mogrify(" 
(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", x) for x in gravar)
     comando = insert + y.decode()
    try:
        cur.execute(comando + "ON CONFLICT (COLUMN1) DO UPDATE;")
        conn.commit()
except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as error:
    print(error)

cur.close()
print('Carga Completa')
else:
conn.close()
print('Nada a Inserir')
```

Muito obrigado pela ajuda, galera!